# Is there a way to run MacOS/OSX apps on Windows, like Wine does?

Tags: windows, macos

This means I'd prefer a solution without virtual machines, and without having to re-compile things unless really necessary.

Comment: No;  There isn't. You removed your only solution.

Comment: Unfortunately not, no. Luckily, macOS sidesteps this problem by not having any software.

Comment: @seagull Ahahahaah that's a good one! However, there indeed may be certain software that is Mac-only.

Answer (score 1):

No, not like WINE.  WINE implements the Windows API in a foreign environment.  It was created over many years by using forms of reverse engineering to figure out what Windows programs needed to have in order to run.  There has been enough interest to sustain the project over the years because there has always been great demand to run Windows-only software combined with a sufficient number of people who are dissatisfied with Windows itself.  The situation with the Mac is the other way around.  People mostly use it because they like the OS but there is relatively little Mac-only software.  On top of that, Apple is more secretive and makes changes to their API more often.  So an equivalent to WINE to run OS X software on Windows would be more difficult to create and have less demand.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other solution possible, or would a VM be necessary?